# Oracle, char(3) variable missing values seem not null nor equal to ''

Tags: oracle, null, char, missing-data

I have a table from which I had this count which highlights the existence of missing values:

```
select tipo, count(*) from mytable group by tipo;
tipo | count(*)
-----+---------
010  | 100
020  | 200
NULL | 300
```

but

```
select * from mytable where tipo is null   ;
select * from mytable where tipo = ''      ;
select * from mytable where tipo like '% %';
```

all return an empty result. "tipo" is a char(3).
How is this possible? What is going on?

-- EDIT --

Just for clarity: the following instead returns the expected results.

```
select * from clabanche where cast(tipo_int as varchar2(3)) is null;
```

So for now I am pre-casting that variable as a varchar2 to circumvent the issue (as suggested by Thorsten in the comments). I guess this is some kind of bad, bad bug...

Comment: Try `where tipo = '   '` (three spaces)

Comment: I tried that as well, still empty. Btw, like '% %' includes this case.

Comment: On a sidenote: Just never use CHAR, always use VARCHAR2. This has bee recommended by Oracle even (in the Ask Tom forum IIRC). CHAR is just very prone to errors and has no benefit over VARCHAR2.

Comment: Please, dump the content of this column: `select distinct dump(tipo, 16) from mytable`. No need to guess what is the real raw value

Comment: I have deleted my answer below as it was wrong. I have tested - on Oracle 21c - as follows: create table mytable (tipo char(3));
insert into mytable values (null);
insert into mytable values (null);
insert into mytable values (null);
commit;
select count(*) from mytable where tipo is null; and I get the result "3". So I don't know why you are not seeing the same

Comment: as a side-note I NEVER use char; always varchar2 ...I don't know of a use case where it is preferable to use char (varchar2 is space efficient and if you want fixed length 3 you could always use something like lpad/rpad(value,3) whichever is more appropriate for your use case)